# CAGradientLayer is going out of frame of UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, calayer, cagradientlayer

I am doing simple things. As I am learning to implement CAGradientLayer.[image]

The gradient you see is of Label. I am using autoresizing(not Autolayout). Apart from this have no code written. Autoresizing is not a problem since I've not touched that.

```
CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [[CAGradientLayer alloc]init];
    gradientLayer.frame  = lblHolder.frame;
    gradientLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor redColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor greenColor] CGColor], nil];
    [lblHolder.layer insertSublayer:gradientLayer atIndex:0];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449256/clipstobounds-how-does-it-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make the following change:

```
gradientLayer.frame  = lblHolder.bounds;
```