# UIView.layer.cornerRadius doesn't work inside uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using UITableView, and I have one UIImageView inside my UITableViewCell, so it set the cornerRadius of the UIImageView, but it doesn't work. How can I fix it?

that is my function to set the content of the cell, and I called it in tableviewdelegate of cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```html
func setContentWithUser(#user: UserMapper) -> Void {
        
        if let avatarUrl = user.avatar{
            self.avatarImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 3
            loadImage(url: avatarUrl, { (image) -> Void in
                self.avatarImageView.image = image
            })
        }
        nameLabel.text = user.name ?? "Unknown"
        titleLabel.text = "blabla"
        hospitalLabel.text = "blabla"
        aboutLabel.text = "blabla""
}
```

Comment: Have you added Quartzcore framework to the project? Then only corner radius will work.

Comment: Sure I did, I use it UIView.layer.cornerRadius = 5 in other places, and that worked. But in UITableViewCell, No

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add this:

```
self.avatarImageView.cliptobounds = true
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but I don't know why it can work?

Comment: @RTzhong You can read more about clipToBounds [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449256/how-does-clipstobounds-work#answer-20449468).