# SegmentControl not clickable in iPhone4s

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol, ios-autolayout

My view hierarchi is like this.
I wanna know the segment view which is inside the `ReturnView` can be covered by the Flex 1lbl or the segment view which is out side from the `ReturnView`

Because when **Returnview comes in iPhone 4s, the segment view which is inside that return view is not clickable. but its working fine in iphone 6+**. What would be the reason for this? Please help me. see below image

[image]

Comment: I think some of the view is overriding on segment view due to constaints or some other stuff may done at coding. Set color to the subview of return view and check. Try to set `clipToSubView` to you return view.

Comment: what is clipTosubview? what does it do?

Comment: also try setting clipToBounds to NO

Comment: The official documentation says the following:

clipsToBounds property

A Boolean value that determines whether subviews are confined to the bounds of the view.

**Discussion**
Setting this value to YES causes subviews to be clipped to the bounds of the receiver. If set to NO, subviews whose frames extend beyond the visible bounds of the receiver are not clipped. The default value is NO.


For More detail refer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449256/how-does-clipstobounds-work

Comment: ohh thanks :) I will try

Comment: You have a constraint error, remove that, there might some view overlapping the segment view.