# Why the badge implemented on the icons are not visible clearly.I want to show the badges clearly on the icons and badge-count on the icons

Tags: objective-c, xcode, view, swift3, badge

The implemented badge is not shown clearly in the interface.why the badge is not clearly visible.
tried zPsoition methods  also.

The below image is shown to describe the issue.

[image]

Comment: How did you setup the interface using interface builder or using code. show us the relevant part regarding constraints, so that we can help

Comment: used coding @sa

Comment: Then show us the code where you've setup the constraints

Comment: do you think that its a constraint issue@SahilManchanda

Comment: if you've used constraints then yes, if you are manually calculating positions and sizes then problem lies there

Comment: Position issue? Or should it be visible above and outside the tile (in the black part)? If yes, it's a mask/clip to bound issue?

Comment: no i have not used constaints there yet.still half of the badge part is visible and half is not.@SahilManchanda

Comment: is there any way to remove the problem of this kind.@Larme

Comment: Could you show what's your current goal?

Comment: my goal is to show the badge at the corner totally circular on which number can be seen@Larme

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449256/how-does-clipstobounds-work ?

Comment: thanks a lot ,mask issue was there @Larme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a mask/clip to bound issue.check your auto layout constraints of that view.